Camera index error with cv2 on my raspberry pi
Ive made a python program that uses yolov5 to detect different things that the camera sees. I use cv2 to get the camera stream to the yolov5 and on my laptop everthing worked good, but when i placed to code on a raspberry pi it didnt work anymore and i get these errors:
[ WARN:0@4.921] global cap_v4l.cpp:997 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video3): can't open camera by index
[ERROR:0@4.922] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:159 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range

Serving Flask app 'test_yolov5'
Debug mode: on
4.9.0
[ WARN:0@4.822] global cap_v4l.cpp:997 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video3): can't open camera by index
[ERROR:0@4.823] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:159 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range

this is my code:
`
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
from yolov5 import YOLOv5
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, Response
import atexit
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='script.log',
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
)

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load YOLOv5 model
model_path = '/home/pi/Desktop/02_codeV2/Test/yolov5n.pt'
logging.info("Loading YOLOv5 model from %s", model_path)
model = YOLOv5(model_path, device="cpu")

# Define class labels
PERSON_CLASS = 0
TREE_CLASS = 1

persons_dict, trees_dict, unknown_dict, last_seen = {}, {}, {}, {}

# Start video capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(3)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)

# Ensure the video capture is released on exit
atexit.register(lambda: (cap.release(), logging.info("Video capture released.")))

def generate_frames():
    logging.info("Started video stream generation.")
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            logging.warning("Failed to read frame from video capture.")
            break

        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        original_height, original_width = frame.shape[:2]
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))

        # Perform inference
        results = model.predict(small_frame)
        detections = results.pandas().xyxy[0]

        now = datetime.now()
        current_detections = set()
        scale_x = original_width / 640
        scale_y = original_height / 480

        # Log detections
        logging.info("Frame processed. Detected objects: %s", detections.to_dict(orient='records'))

        for index, row in detections.iterrows():
            x1, y1 = int(row['xmin'] * scale_x), int(row['ymin'] * scale_y)
            x2, y2 = int(row['xmax'] * scale_x), int(row['ymax'] * scale_y)
            label, pos_x = row['name'], (x1 + x2) / 2

            if label == 'person':
                color = (0, 255, 0)
                key = f'person_{index}'
                persons_dict[key] = pos_x
            elif label == 'tree':
                color = (0, 255, 255)
                key = f'tree_{index}'
                trees_dict[key] = pos_x
            else:
                color = (255, 0, 0)
                key = f'unknown_{index}'
                unknown_dict[key] = pos_x

            last_seen[key] = now
            current_detections.add(key)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, label, (x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)

        for obj_dict in [persons_dict, trees_dict, unknown_dict]:
            keys_to_remove = [k for k in obj_dict.keys() if k not in current_detections and (now - last_seen[k]).total_seconds() > 1]
            for k in keys_to_remove:
                del obj_dict[k]
                del last_seen[k]
                logging.info("Removed %s from tracking due to inactivity.", k)

        cv2.putText(frame, now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)

        _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + buffer.tobytes() + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>YOLOv5 Video Stream</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>YOLOv5 Video Stream</h1>
            <img src="/video_feed" width="1920" height="1080">
        </body>
    </html>
    """


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    port = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 6234
    logging.info("Starting Flask app on port %d.", port)
    try:
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error occurred: %s", str(e))


Ive done some googling and someone said to make the camera index (-1) and not (0) but that didint help. i dont realy now what to do to fix this now, ive been struggeling for a week now.
i'm running on a raspberrypi 5 4gb and pi os full

Are you using a USB camera? in your code you have cap = cv2.VideoCapture(3) its the 3 that is causing the problem.

Yes i'm using a usb camera and ive tried everything from -1 to 100 with a test program and on all of them i get the same error.

Are both laptop and USB camera 2.0 or 3.0?

prototype this with ffmpeg/ffplay (test the camera access). that way, we can remove OpenCV from this situation. This is likely not an OpenCV issue.

With the USB camera plugged in open a command terminal and enter lsusb what do you get? Is the camera listed?
